# What's the need for XmlInclude declaration?

Tags: c#

I've inherited some old code for a webservice. At the top are dozens of XmlInclude declarations for each object the web services spits out:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlInclude(typeof(...))]
```

Removing these seems to have no adverse effect. So i'm wondering if someone can explain to me:

1. What are the need for these?
2. What will removing these affect? Project build fine without them so i am assuming that any adverse effects will only be seen at runtime?

I have done my research on this and understand the general purpose of the XmlInclude element is to add multiple schemas with the same target namespace, but if there is a need for them in this code then should removing them not cause compile errors?

Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Rule number 1: don't touch if it works. Have you read what they do on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)? As for what may happens (you don't show the code), read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302290.aspx).

Comment: If it builds fine, wouldn't the next logical step be to run it?

Comment: There won't be compile errors, but there might be runtime errors. It is just that (de)serializing of derived types won't work, isn't it? And if there are such scenarios in your code, you will see the errors.

Comment: I apologize i guess my question was a broad and general one. @Sinatr thanks for the link, this is helpful!